# Android Expand/Collapse to show/hide buttons/texts/Imageviews in the middle of the display

Tags: android, layout, android-toolbar, show-hide, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

as you can read from the title i am looking for a method to collapse a layout into a drawable line (not to the top of the display) 
it should hide/show a layout with buttons texts etc. 
This should take place more or less in the middle of the activity layout.

I attached some pictures, which shows what exactly i  need

when closed

[image]

when opened

[image]

Thanks for any answer

Comment: Do you want to implement something like expandable list view?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. So i was able to solve the complete issue. But the only thing left is, how can i collapse the layout to a line drawable?